# How to create onClick javascript event to redirect it to another website?

Tags: javascript, onclick

I have wordpress website using GTranslate. As I made Chinese version of the website, I want that when someone click on 'Chinese' in drop down menu of GTranslate, I actually send him to new Chinese website. GTranslate plugin developer told me I need to create Javascript onclick event for that. how can i do this please?

When someone select this in drop down of GTranslate:

Chinese (Simplified)

I need to send them to a new URL.
Can you please show me Javascript and how to implement it - where to place script?